# Reading large text files with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, ipython, large-files

I have been trying to read a few large text files (sizes around 1.4GB - 2GB) with Pandas, using the `read_csv` function, with no avail. Below are the versions I am using:

- Python 2.7.6
- Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit) (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
- IPython 1.1.0
- Pandas 0.13.1

I tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data.txt')
```

and it crashed Ipython with a message: `Kernel died, restarting`.

Then I tried using an iterator:

```
tp = pd.read_csv('data.txt', iterator = True, chunksize=1000)
```

again, I got the `Kernel died, restarting` error.

Any ideas? Or any other way to read big text files?

Thank you!

Comment: I did not get this error on my machine, with a similar configuration than yours. How much RAM memory do you have? On my machine Python needed a peak of around 5GB to read a csv with 2.9 GB using `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: @SaulloCastro My machine has 8GB installed. It should be able to handle such a filesize, since most of the installed RAM is available, I am not running anything else.

Answer (score 9):

A solution for a similar question was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) some time after the posting of this question. Basically, it suggests to read the file in `chunks` by doing the following:

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6  # number of rows per chunk
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

You should specify the `chunksize` parameter accordingly to your machine's capabilities (that is, make sure it can process the chunk).

Comment: what is 10 ** 6, please enlighten us lesser enlightened ones?? Also, this does not give the solution of storing the chunk into dataframe  and concatenation of all such dataframes afterwards.

Comment: That 10 raise to power 6 is intuitive. what is it KB, MB, lines in the file, what is it ???

Comment: Perhaps a more explanatory and useful link be mentioned here :  https://pythondata.com/working-large-csv-files-python/

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't get you quite right. It's number of rows per chunk.

Comment: I suggest you check the target dupe question as it has relevant and useful info for you :) thanks for the link also, will check it out